# Error importing the mnist module when using pypy

Tags: python, mnist, pypy, mlp

I'm currently building a MLP network using the MNIST data set in python. My script can import the mnist module and access the datasets when it's running in the default runtime environment but whenever I try to run it using pypy I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LearningProgram.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mnist import MNIST
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnist'
```

This is how I import mnist if it matters

```
from mnist import MNIST
import random
import numpy as np
import math
from math import e
from math import log
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling mnist but it didn't work. I'm also using python 3.8.1

Comment: Maybe you did `pip install mnist` instead of `pip3 install mnist`?

Comment: I didn't even know there was a difference, but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling mnist using pip3 and I still get the same error

Comment: Install `tensorflow-datasets` then do `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tensorflow.datasets.mnist.load_data()`

Comment: `pip` and `pip3` install for whatever Python version it comes with.  It's probably a different one.  Try instead `pypy3 -m ensurepip; pypy3 -mpip install mnist` (or the exact version of cpython or pypy you're using).

Comment: I hope you are using the conda pypy environment, but even then your chances of being able to import tensorflow into pypy are slim.

https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/

Comment: @ArminRigo that seemed to work, I was able to install mnist but now I'm having trouble installing numpy with pypy. But this isn't really a problem since my script isn't dependent on numpy. Thanks for your help!